# Specify column index of selected data in ItemBox to retrieve when iterating through selected items

Tags: vba, ms-word

Basically have an ItemBox with three columns in an Access form. I want to get specific columns when I iterate though the selected items, but I am having difficulty doing so.

```
Function GetSelectedValues(famList As Variant) As Collection

    Dim famListColl As New Collection

    ' Loop through all of the selected surveys
    For Each fam In famList.ItemsSelected
        Debug.Print (fam) ' prints the index number of the selected item
        Debug.Print (famList.ItemData(fam)) ' this prints out the last columns value for the selected item
        famListColl.Add famList.ItemData(fam)
    Next

    Set GetSelectedValues = famListColl

End Function
```

If I try to do the following I get an `Run-time error '424': Object required error`:

```
Debug.Print(fam.Column(1))
Debug.Print(famList.ItemData(fam).Column(1))
```

This somewhat works, but only displays the values of the first selected item indefinitely (it doesn't iterate):

```
Debug.Print(famList.Column(1))
```

So I need to combine the two somehow, but struggling to figure that much.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: The parentheses are extraneous and are causing the parenthesized expression to be evaluated as a value. `Debug.Print fam.Column(1)` - depending on what `.Column(1)` yields, these parentheses could ultimately be why you're getting error 424

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stumbled across [this post](https://www.access-programmers.co.uk/forums/showthread.php?t=130515) that helped me sort it out. I doubt I would have figured it out otherwise. Looks like this:

```
Debug.Print (famList.Column(2, fam))
```

So the entire solution for me is the following:

```
Function GetSelectedValues(famList As Variant) As Collection

    Dim famListColl As New Collection

    ' Loop through all of the selected surveys
    For Each fam In famList.ItemsSelected
        famListColl.Add famList.Column(1, fam)
        famListColl.Add famList.Column(2, fam)
    Next

    Set GetSelectedValues = famListColl

End Function
```